# "Having /To have + past participle + object + action verb " VS "Havin/To having +past participle+ object +Be verb"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

1. Having got a goal in my first international match was a great achievement.
2. To have got a goal in my first international match was a great achievement.
3. Having got a goal in my first international match made me so happy.
4. To have got a goal in my first international made me so happy.

Are all of these sentences correct?  Can I use any types of verb with perfect infinitive and perfect gerund?

Comment: So your question is: **_"Which is correct? 'Having got' or 'To have got'?_** Is that correct?

Comment: @P.E. Dant Just consider all of my sentences and tell me,  is there any incorrect sentence ? If there is, then tell my why?  I think by this, I would get all of my answers.

Comment: None of your sentences are incorrect. Any English speaker will understand you clearly. You could also write either **_"Having made a doughnut..."_** or **_"To have made a doughnut..."_**